# Cocos2d CCLabelBMFont how to add a background to string

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am wondering how can I add a border & background to labels generated via CCLabelBMFont class in cocos2d.

I don't want to use sprites because my labels are generated on the fly and will keep changing and the size of labels are also different.

Also, I want user to touch and move these labels across the screen. When user picks a label it wiggles a bit like in free air. In that case, I wish to keep low complexity and preserve memory and cpu calculations.

Anyone knows best ways to achieve this?

IOS app LetterPress has similar effects.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class, that will incapsulate creation of complex node.

It will have several layers, for example, the first layer can be simple CCLayerColor of given rect with zOrder -2, the next layer will be your CCLabelBMFont with zOrder -1 and then you can overload `draw` method to draw border over your control. All that you draw in this method will be drawn with zOrder 0.

Then you can encapsulate any effects in this class. For example, you can rotate it a bit with method `pick`, etc. Whatever you want.